# Mxnet R package compilation

Tags: 20.04, compiling, r

I am interested in using the mxnet library in R programming language. However there is absence of instructions regarding how to compile the R package in Ubuntu. The make rpkg command is not functioning in the latest versions. I was wondering on whether there are people who could clarify. I have already compiled the mxnet  I guess successfully and with -DUSE_CPP_PACKAGE=1.

Thank you

Comment: What is the exact name of R package? I can't find mxnet at [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html).

Comment: Its not at CRAN. It's at: mxnet.apache.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that modern Git master version of mxnet do not have `R-package` sub-folder.
It was here until [Jun 22, 2020](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/commit/2fbec60e0da8832d71f7e3f93d4407dbca745e51). So one should use [previous 1.8.0 version](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/tree/v1.8.x/R-package) of the library.

So one needs to clone the v1.8.0 branch and then compile and install it. On my system I did this with commands shown below:

```
sudo apt-get install git

cd ~/Downloads
git clone --recursive https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet mxnet -b v1.8.x

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential git ninja-build ccache libopenblas-dev libopencv-dev cmake
sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-cuda-dev nvidia-cuda-gdb nvidia-cuda-toolkit nvidia-cuda-toolkit-gcc # Nvidia CUDA
sudo apt-get install -y libmkl-full-dev # MKL

cd mxnet
cmake .
make -j$(nproc)
sudo make install
```

Then install R binding consulting with *docs/static_site/src/pages/get_started
/ubuntu_setup.md* locally or [online](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/blob/v1.8.x/docs/static_site/src/pages/get_started/ubuntu_setup.md):

```
sudo apt-get install -y r-base-core r-cran-devtools libcairo2-dev libxml2-dev libssl-dev
```

Inside `R` session execute `install.packages("roxygen2")` specifying user's library.

Then:

```
cd ~/Downloads/mxnet
cp -v lib/libmxnet.so R-package/inst/libs/
make -f R-package/Makefile rpkg
```

To test the R package use:

```
Rscript -e 'library(mxnet);a <- mx.nd.ones(c(2,3), ctx = mx.cpu());b <- a * 2 + 1;b'
make -f R-package/Makefile rpkgtest
```